# NameError: name 'file_content' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, word-cloud

I did an assignment on **Coursera** and successfully passed that.I compiled and got accurate result on **Jupyter notebook**.
https://poskzjbvcahynihgdhljpw.coursera-apps.org/notebooks/C1M6L2_Final_Project_V3.ipynb
I typed on my **pycharm** the similar code:

But I got an error:

```
import wordcloud
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display
import fileupload
import io
import sys

# This is the uploader widget

def _upload():

    _upload_widget = fileupload.FileUploadWidget()

    def _cb(change):
        global file_contents
        decoded = io.StringIO(change['owner'].data.decode('utf-8'))
        filename = change['owner'].filename
        print('Uploaded `{}` ({:.2f} kB)'.format(
            filename, len(decoded.read()) / 2 **10))
        file_contents = decoded.getvalue()

    _upload_widget.observe(_cb, names='data')
    display(_upload_widget)

_upload()


def calculate_frequencies(file_contents):
    # Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words,use to process the text
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its",
                           "they", "them", "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be",
                           "been", "being", "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when",
                           "where", "how", "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very",
                           "can", "will", "just"]
    count_frequency = {}

    for contents in file_contents:
        if (contents not in punctuations) and (contents not in uninteresting_words):
            if contents not in count_frequency:
                count_frequency[contents] = 1
            else:
                count_frequency[contents] += 1

    # wordcloud
    cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
    cloud.generate_from_frequencies(count_frequency)
    return cloud.to_array()


# Displaying my wordcloud image

myimage = calculate_frequencies(file_contents)
plt.imshow(myimage, interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ashik/PycharmProjects/RawCodes/final_project_google_crash_course_with_python.py", line 54, in <module>
        myimage = calculate_frequencies(file_content)
    NameError: name 'file_content' is not defined
    FileUploadWidget(label='Browse', _dom_classes=('widget_item', 'btn-group'))
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: as the assignment stated, we need to download a book and run the cell contain _upload function, there is a button will browser your local disk, upload the book, if success, there is a statement: Uploaded `bible.txt` (4349.56 kB), and then, everything passed.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following changes :

1.

```
def _cb(change):
   global file_contents
```

2. 

```
myimage = calculate_frequencies(file_contents)
```

Should fix the issue

Comment: Oh! That was my typing mistake typing "global file_content" rather "global file_contents "
But, not at all. Same error showing :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following steps:

> IMPORTANT! If this was your first time running the above cell
> containing the installs and imports, you will need save this notebook
> now. Then under the File menu above, select Close and Halt. When the
> notebook has completely shut down, reopen it. This is the only way the
> necessary changes will take affect.
>
> To upload your text file, run the following cell that contains all the
> code for a custom uploader widget. Once you run this cell, a "Browse"
> button should appear below it. Click this button and navigate the
> window to locate your saved text file.